Using Karate 1.4.1 version seeing ClassNotFoundException on running the feature file
I changed my karate core version from 1.4.0.RC3 to 1.4.1 and seeing the below error on running the feature file in eclipse. May I please get an help to resolve the issue for using the v 1.4.1 in both eclipse and intelliJ. I want to run the feature file only
Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main
Caused by: Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cucumber.api.cli.Main
